# Continuity of $\delta_E : (X, \tau_d) \rightarrow (R, \varepsilon_1): \delta_E(p) = d(p, E)$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d) $be a metric space and $E \subseteq X$.

We define $d(p,E) = inf \{ d(p, q)| q \in E \}$ the distance from $ p \in X$ to $E$

I have the following example in my lecture notes:

**Problem:**

Let $(X, d)$be a metric space and $E \subseteq X$.Now, the function
$\delta_E : (X, \tau_d) \rightarrow (R, \varepsilon_1)$ defined by  $\delta_E(p) = d(p, E)$ is continuous

**Proof**

Let $p_0 \in X$ and let $d_0 = \delta_E(p_0) \in \mathbb{R}$. For each $p \in X$ and $q \in E $ we have

$d(p, q)  \leq  d(p, p_0) + d(p_0,q)$  **........(1)**

and $d(p_0, q) ≤ d(p_0, p) + d(p, q)$
from which

$\delta_E(p) = inf_{q \in E}d(p, q) ≤ d(p, p_0) + \delta_E(p_0)$ and $\delta_E(p_0) ≤ d(p_0, p) + \delta_E(p)$:

Therefore,  $|\delta_E(p) − \delta_E(p_0)| = |\delta_E(p) − d_0| ≤ d(p, p_0)$.

Now, given $\epsilon > 0, V_{\epsilon} = (d_0 −
\epsilon, d_0 +\epsilon) $ is the ball of center $d_0 $ and radious $\epsilon > 0 $ in $(\mathbb{R}, d_{\varepsilon})$ and $\delta_E(B(p_0, \epsilon)) \subseteq V_{\varepsilon}$, **........(2)**

from which we get the continuity of $ \delta_E$.

**I am having trouble understanding (1) and (2) :**

(1)$\delta_E(p) = inf_{q \in E}d(p, q) ≤ d(p, p_0) + \delta_E(p_0)$
How did the last term $\delta_E(p_0)$ get here?

(2) how do they get this expresion: $\delta_E(B(p_0, \epsilon)) \subseteq V_{\varepsilon}$ ? I tried to take an element in the left set and prove it is the right one , but I am not getting anywhere. I know that to prove continuity I must show the first ball is contained in the second one

Can someone please detail what is going on?

Comment: \inf looks better than inf.  And we should assume E is not empty.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint for (1)** Take infimum over $q$ on *both* sides
of the given inequality

$$d(p, q)  \leq  d(p, p_0) + d(p_0,q)$$

Use the general statement: If for every $y$ in set of real numbers $B$ there is an $x$ in set of real numbers $A$ such that $x\leq y$, then
$$ \inf A \leq \inf B.$$

**Edit:**  Take:
$$A = \{ d(p, q) \mid q \in E \}$$
$$B = \{ d(p, p_0) + d(p_0,q) \mid q \in E \} $$
and then note that:
$$ \inf B = d(p, p_0) + \inf \; \{  d(p_0,q) \mid q \in E \} $$

**Hint for (2)** From
$$|\delta_E(p) − \delta_E(p_0)|≤ d(p, p_0),$$
if $p \in B(p_0,\epsilon)$, then

$$ |\delta_E(p) -\delta_E(p_0)| ≤ d(p, p_0) < \epsilon. $$

That is

$$ \delta_E(p) \in B(\delta_E(p_0), \epsilon)=V_\epsilon $$

for all $p \in B(p_0,\epsilon)$.

Comment: I was thinking that, but I was not sure if it could be done, I am trying to find a theorem to justify it. All I can find are properties for sets and inclusion, but here we have an inequality

Comment: Note that $d(p,p_0)$ is independent of $q$ and remember the definitions of $\delta_E(p)$ and $\delta_E(p_0)$  .

Comment: Yeah taking the inf will yield the result directly, it's clear, but can I really take the inf of numbers in an inequality an distribute it over a sum? I know I can take the inf for sets like in $A \subseteq B$

Comment: @J.C.VegaO I added the general $\inf$ statement that should help.

Answer (score 0):

A more clear proof:

*Proof*. In order to show that $\delta_E : X \to \mathbb R$ is continuous, we show that $\delta_E$ is continuous at every $p_0 \in X$, that is, we show that for all $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $$\delta_E(B(p_0,\delta)) \subseteq (\delta_E(p_0)-\varepsilon,\delta_E(p_0)+\varepsilon),$$ in other words, for all $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ with the following property:
$$\textrm{for all $p \in X$ such that $d(p,p_0)<\delta$ we have $|\delta_E(p)-\delta_E(p_0)|<\varepsilon.$}$$

So, let $p_0 \in X$ be arbitrary, and $\varepsilon>0$ also arbitrary. We claim that $\delta := \varepsilon/2$ works. To see this, let $p \in X$ such that $d(p,p_0) < \delta$ and now note that:

- For any $q \in E$ we have $\delta_E(p) \leq d(p,q) \leq d(p,p_0)+d(p_0,q) < \delta +d(p_0,q)$, or,
  $$\delta_E(p) - \delta < d(p_0,q)$$
  meaning that the set $\{d(p_0,q) : q \in E\}$ is bounded below by $\delta_E(p) - \delta$. Now, since $\delta_E(p_0)$ is the greatest lower bound for $\{d(p_0,q) : q \in E\}$ we have $\delta_E(p) - \delta \leq \delta_E(p_0)$, i.e.
  $$\delta_E(p) - \delta_E(p_0) \leq \delta < \varepsilon.$$
- Similarly we can obtain the other inequality: $-\varepsilon < \delta_E(p) - \delta_E(p_0)$.